# Got hibernate Exception while doing multi-tenancy program

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, multi-tenant

I developed code regarding multi-tenancy with hibernate.when I tried to run my code it gives exception in configuration.buildSessionFactory.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Mappings;)V
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1404)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at my.com.MultiTenancyPkg.MultitenancyMain.main(MultitenancyMain.java:20)
```

I have import above list of jars in my code:

```
          commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
          commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
          dom4j-1.6.1.jar
          ejb3-persistence.jar
          h2-1.0.60.jar
          hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar
          hibernate-annotations.jar
          hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
          hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
          hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar
          hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar
          hibernate3.jar
          jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
          jta-1.1.jar
          postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar
          postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar
          slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta1.jar
```

If anyone has the solution on this please share there ideas/views.Thanks

Comment: Could it be you mix Hibernate version 3 with version 4? You have some jars in version 3.xx and some in 4.xx! How do you import these jars?

Comment: @michal For multi-tenancy, I need some of the jar from hibernate version 3 and some of from hibernate version 4, due to this that might be created compatibility error.Do you have any solution for implement multi-tenancy with hibernate?

Comment: Maybe explain what exactly do you mean by multi-tenancy. There should never be any reason to use 2 different hibernate versions and mixing jars with different versions is definitely not supported.

Comment: @user158037 , Multi-Tenancy means, one application serves the different number of the client using tenantId.Example: We can handle more than one database of client in single application.

Comment: I would not use framework feature for multi-tenancy. I would develop the feature on my own, including Client table and client_id in my model.